# Arithmetic and Geometric progression question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

5, x, y are three consecutive terms of an AP and x, y, 81 are three consecutive terms of a GP ( x and y are whole numbers). Calculate
(a) The values of x and y
(b) The 8th term of the AP
(c) The sum of the first 8 terms of the GP

Comment: Please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x = 5 + d$

$y = 5 + 2d$

$y = rx$

$81 = r^2x$

You have four equations with four unknowns, just solve them.

You should get $x=25$ and $y=45$. Just use the formulas $a +(n-1)d$ and $\dfrac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$ for part (b) and (c).